# Mathlive library in angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, symbolic-math

I use [mathlive library](https://github.com/arnog/mathlive) in my angular project.
While I run the code the

```
<math-field> {{'$$x=\frac {-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}} {2a} $$'}} </math-field>
```

It gives the following error:

> unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{'{'}}.

When the `{}` comes, then only it shows error. Otherwise, the code runs.

```
<math-field>f(x) = \sin(x+\pi) </math-field>
```

this code run perfectly. I used different formats like

```
<math-field> $$ f(x) = \sin(x+\pi) $$ </math-field>
```

```
<math-field> {{'f(x) = \sin(x+\pi)'}} </math-field>
```

It gives exact out.

```
<math-field> {{'x=\ frac {-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}} {2a}'}} </math-field>
```

```
<math-field> {{'$$x=\ frac {-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}} {2a} $$'}} </math-field>
```

```
<math-field> {{'x=\ frac {-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}} {2a}'}} </math-field>
```

```
<math-field> {{'$$x=\ frac {-b\pm \sqrt {b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$'}}</math-field>
```

The output:
x = (2a - b) ± √(b² - 4ac)

Answer (score 0):

As indicate in the error you use `{{'{'}}` to a `{` and `{{'}'}}` to a `}`

```
//in stead of
<math-field> x=\frac {-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}} {2a} </math-field>

//try
<math-field> x=\\frac {{'{'}}-b\pm \sqrt{{'{'}}b^2-4ac{{'}'}}{{'}'}} {{'{'}}2a{{'}'}} </math-field>
```

or use a variable

```
form='x=\frac {-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}} {2a} ' 

<math-field>{{form}}</mat-field>
```